# How to solve "Error: 0x80070002 the system cannot find the file specified " When installing windows subsystem for linux

Tags: linux, windows, file, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm experiencing an error while installing the Ubuntu distribution in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Previously, I attempted to install it with a different user, but I had to remove it. Could this possibly be the cause of the issue?[image: error when installing]

I tried enabling BIOS virtualization but it didn't work